# Problems with decimal column in webshop

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal, decimalformat

In a webshop product table, i have a column, called minimum_order. This is the minimum quantity, that i can order from this product.

If i give 1 for this data, it stores that in the table like 1.00. The column type is decimal, 10.2

On my product page, when i want to add it to the basket, i get an error, that i cant order 1 of this product, because the minimum order is 1.00

What am i doing wrong?

**Update:**

So i echo the minimum order value of the product to a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" value="'.$kat['termek_min_order'].'" id="MinimumOrder'.intval($kat['termek_id']).'">
```

In the browser when i view the source, that inputs value is 1.00

Add to cart with javascript:

```
function add_to_cart(termek_id)
{
    var darabszam = $.trim($('#item_darabszam'+termek_id).val()); // The quantity i typed in, that i want to order
    var MinimumOrder = $.trim($('#MinimumOrder'+termek_id).val()); // The minimum order value
    var CartErrors = [];
    if(darabszam == "") { CartErrors.push("No value, or 0 was typed."); }
    if(darabszam < MinimumOrder) { CartErrors.push("The minimum order of this product is "+MinimumOrder+"."); }

    if(CartErrors.length == 0 )
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'files/add_to_kosar.php',
            data: { termek_id: termek_id, darab: darabszam, MinimumOrder: MinimumOrder },
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function(data)
            {
                kosartetelek();
                var result = $.trim(data);
                $('#CartModalResult').html(data);
                $('.CartModalTitle').html('Added to basket ok');
                $('#CartModal').modal('show');
                checkprice();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('.CartModalTitle').html('Error while adding to basket.');
        $('#CartModalResult').fadeIn('slow').html('<div class="javascript_error_div">'+(CartErrors.join('<br/>'))+'</div>');
        $('#CartModal').modal('show');
    }
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $('#CartModal').modal('hide');
    },  10000 );
}
```

So at this product, if i want to order 1, i get an error, that i have to order minium 1.00

Do i really need decimal typed column for this? What does the float type column do?

Comment: Yes, it is. If we have building material products on the shop, you can order 12.96, 5.5 and more.

Comment: In that case show us some code. How do you evaluate whether the minimum order limit is reached?

Comment: I will send it from home  later. What code do you need? The quantity validating when adding something to the basket, or what?

Comment: Validation seems the issue, so that would be a good start.

Comment: Hello, i added it to my first post. Thank you!

Comment: You mention several times that you get an error but you don't say which one.

Comment: Please add javascript tag. That's much more relevant than sql. I don't know javascript

Comment: Also, it would help if you translated those messages, so people understand what you are trying to do, if nothing else.

Comment: Finally, technically, it's correct. Since `1` can be anything from `0.5` to `1.4`, it can be smaller than `1.00`. I think you'll have to explicitly convert.

Comment: I transleted the messages.

Comment: Please point to the specific line that compares 1 to 1.00.

Comment: Theres no compare, i think. In my function, the second if is checking, that the entered value is = or bigger than the minimum order.